# Logging into Facebook XMPP with encrypted access token format 

Tags: facebook, authentication

Problem with my accessToken!!

accessToken is all right all the time.

It's standard format: AAA|BBB|CCC

I can get available current user's uid and session secret from a given accessToken( AAA|BBB|CCC)

BUT  today fb server give me a strange accessToken unexpectedly.It's not useful for xmpplogin.

eg. AAACmERnbMSwBAB3XnOt4hnR71agtbo3CE8w2Xd7jD7QEURSiiOFV1Eg85tHsaHvVNobiUFppqzQcaXKjWOVSZCIFKvVsEJ4llZBfNI6AZDZD

could you give me a clue?I'm crazy to find answers whole day.

Comment: When I login today I receive similar access token, but it doesn't prevent me from using any functionality. (I'm using Facebook C# SDK)

Comment: @fansmey are you not getting your desired information with new access token?

Answer (score 1):

As per https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/572/ the access token format changed recently to an encrypted format.  All the APIs should work fine using this encrypted token including XMPP but it requires a minor code change to your XMPP code.

There was a blog post showing how to use the access token for XMPP auth on [Sep 10](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/555/).

Replace the `session_key` and `sig` parameters with the `access_token` parameter which should be the user access_token which has the `xmpp_login` permission - also note that it needs to be passed over SSL (which I believe was optional when you were only passing only the session key and sig)

If you can't get XMPP login working when you pass the encrypted access token, please file a bug in [Facebook's bug tracker](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs), but make sure you have the parameters changed per the note above and the  [chat docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/).

Comment: @lgy   // creates the response array
  $resp_array = array(
    'method' => $challenge_array['method'],
    'nonce' => $challenge_array['nonce'],
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'api_key' => $options['app_id'],
    'call_id' => 0,
    'v' => '1.0',
  );
  // creates signature
  $response = http_build_query($resp_array);

Answer (score 0):

The format of Facebook access token has changed recently. Now it is encrypted. At present if you want to get the user id of the owner of an access token issue a request in the following format

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token='accesstoken'

This will return the Facebook User id of the owner of access token as a Json string. This request works even when the user is not logged in.